# SQL Server Conditional statement in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to write a SQL query that retrieves records based on supplied `RoleId`.

e.g.

- If RoleId = 1 THEN _t1.CreatedBy = @LoginUserId.

For other RoleId, I want all records from table without any condition on `CreatedBy` column.

I am providing sample query as per my requirement.

```
SELECT _t1.*
FROM [dbo].[TblPassDetail] _t1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TblVisitor] _t2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON _t1.VisitorId = _t2.SrNo 
WHERE _t1.LocationId = @LocationId
  AND _t1.CreatedBy = (CASE WHEN @RoleId = 1 THEN @LoginUserId ELSE 0 END)
```

Issue is that if supplied `@RoleId` is 1, I am getting all records for that `LoginUserId`, but if `@RoleId` is anything other than 1, then I am not getting any records as SQL checking records for `_t1.CreatedBy = 0` which doesn't exist in the table.

Any suggestion on how to rewrite my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rephrase the difficult part of your `WHERE` clause to this:

```
@RoleId = 1 AND _t1.CreatedBy = @LoginUserId
OR
@RoleId <> 1
```

In other words, if the `RoleId` is `1`, then the logged in user must be the creator.  But for other `RoleId` values there is no such dependence on the logged in user.  Here is the full query:

```
SELECT _t1.*
FROM [dbo].[TblPassDetail] _t1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TblVisitor] _t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON _t1.VisitorId = _t2.SrNo 
WHERE
    _t1.LocationId = @LocationId AND
    (
        (@RoleId = 1 AND _t1.CreatedBy = @LoginUserId) OR
        @RoleId <> 1
    );
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you so much, my query worked perfectly by replacing CASE WHEN statement with the above 'AND-OR' combination. I am struggling with several combinations of CASE WHEN statement for this.
Thanks Again.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achiving this would be to convert your `CASE` statement into an `OR`:

```
SELECT _t1.*
FROM [dbo].[TblPassDetail] _t1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[TblVisitor] _t2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON _t1.VisitorId = _t2.SrNo 
WHERE _t1.LocationId = @LocationId
      AND ( (_t1.CreatedBy = @LoginUserId AND @RoleID = 1) OR @RoleID <> 1)
```

Another way, kind of a workaround would be the following, but since LIKE is used, you would need to check the execution plan and performance of it:

```
SELECT _t1.*
FROM [dbo].[TblPassDetail] _t1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[TblVisitor] _t2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON _t1.VisitorId = _t2.SrNo 
WHERE _t1.LocationId = @LocationId
AND _t1.CreatedBy LIKE (CASE WHEN @RoleId = 1 THEN @LoginUserId ELSE '%%' END)
```

Comment: Thanks Rigerta for your reply. I resolve my issue by using 1st approach.

Answer (score 0):

Get all records when <> 1

```
(@RoleId = 1 AND _t1.CreatedBy = @RoleId) OR ISNULL(@RoleId,0)<> 1
```